# Update existing class definition by source package

Tags: java, spring, maven, bytecode, java-bytecode-asm

I have a jar file which contains 5 classes. I just want to change one logic in that class.

BaseClass is the one I need to fix. Please check the following base structure.
I just need to remove one line and add 3 lines in `changeMe` method.

**Class structure**

```
package com.temp;

public class BaseClass{
    public interface IClassA{ String sayRaw(String raw); }
    private BaseClass(){}
    protected static class ClassToFix extends ClassParent {
         @Override public void changeMe ()  {
                ........
         }
    }
}


//---------Source from jar file--------------
package com.temp;

public class ClassA implements IClassA{
    public static final BaseClass.IClassA ABC = ....;
    String sayRaw(String raw){
    } 

}
```

**What I tried**

1. The class is not having public constructor, so extending the class options is out.
2. I tried method interceptor from bytebuddy, same problem occurred.
3. Finally I tried javaassist. It also not working, because it is not updating method definition in a jar file.

I did create same package in my src directory and copied the class definition and added my fix. This fix is working in Dynamic web project, but not in Maven Java project. It is stating linkage error

> ClassA is implementation of interface (IClassA) from BaseClass which
>   is the modified source.
>
> java.lang.LinkageError: loader constraint violation: when resolving
>   field "ABC" the class loader (instance of
>   org/springframework/boot/devtools/restart/classloader/RestartClassLoader)
>   of the referring class, com/temp/ClassA, and the class loader
>   (instance of sun/misc/Launcher$AppClassLoader) for the field's
>   resolved type, com/temp/BaseClass$IClassA, have different Class
>   objects for that type

Suggest me if there is any other way to fix this.

Comment: It's potentially troublesome to have different versions of the same class in your classpath.  My recommendation would be to recompile all five classes with any needed modifications, jar them up, and use your jar only.

Comment: clone the source of the class, and then pull the class out of the jar that ships it, maybe using something like arquillian (or like we do by unpacking the jars ourselves in deploy). I don't *really* recommend this but... it works

Comment: there may be other options depending on how you are using this class and why you need to "monkey patch" it

Answer (score 1):

You cannot create a class at runtime that you are not allowed to create at compile time. The JVM verifies any class before loading it and will disallow what you attempt.

Using Byte Buddy or Javassist, you can however define a so-called Java-agent that you can add upon startup. Doing so, you can redefine your `ClassToFix` when it is first loaded.

Byte Buddy includes an `AgentBuilder` abstraction which makes this rather easy to implement. You can find [tutorials on how to implement an agent online](https://www.infoq.com/articles/Easily-Create-Java-Agents-with-ByteBuddy). Javassist does not provide mechanisms to define a Java agent but it allows you to redefine classes when creating your own `ClassFileTransformer`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Actually similar to the one you said, I'm doing right now. I'm creating new classpool and adding the jar into it and trying to change the bytecode. It is working sometimes, some times not. It was working in debug mode and not in run mode. It is so wired man. Do you have any idea about it?

Comment: You are probably attaching the agent asynchronously. In this case, if the agent is attached after a class is loaded, you have to explicitly redefine it (`Instrumentation::retransformClasses`). Otherwise, the class is not instrumented.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried aspects? Aspect creates proxy for object of any non-final class (but I am not sure whether it works with private constructors) and allows you to intercept request to any method. So you can write custom logic.

Comment: If I use aspects I need to give the object to the caller side. That will not work out for my problem.